# Which CPU ABI is prefer for app?

Tags: android, android-ndk, cpu

In my Nokia 5 `android.os.Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS = ["arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"]`. When I run app with arch specific `*.so` files for all this architectures Nokia 5 choose `arm64-v8a/*.so` libs. Question: how I can programmatically to know which architectures will be used for my app in another concrete device?

Comment: [`Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SUPPORTED_ABIS) _"The most preferred ABI is the first element in the list"_. Note that starting sometime in 2019 you will be required to include a 64-bit version of any library for which you have a 32-bit version.

Comment: What if app running in compatiblity mode with other ABI?

Comment: Well, you should intersect the set of supported ABIs with the set of ABIs you provide libraries for. With your example from the Nokia 5, if you provide arm64-v8a libraries then those would be selected because they are the most preferred ones, Otherwise, if you provide armeabi-v7a libraries, those would be selected, and so on.

Comment: Let's say, that I provide libraries only for `armeabi` and run my app in Nokia 5, how I can programatically to know, that app running in compatibility mode with architecture `armeabi`? In code I do not know about `*.so` files, which provided or which not.

Comment: _"In code I do not know about *.so files, which provided or which not."_ Two questions arise: 1) why wouldn't you be able to know this in your code? For example, you could create an array member of `BuildConfig` with the ABIs you support. And question 2 is why do you need to know which library is being used at all? What is the actual problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Michael Original problem: I have two different implementation of barcode scanner: for `armeabi-v7a` and for `arm64-v8a`. In app I must understand which implementation I would use. Let us suppose on some device `SUPPORTED_ABIS = [`x86`]`, and my app will run in compativility mode with some ABI, how i can select the scanner implementation? Probably, I can write JNI function for all ABIs which will return name of arch - and I will solve my problem. But, may be, there is more elegant solution?

Comment: _"In app I must understand which implementation I would use"_ But why do you need that information? Don't the libraries do the same thing regardless of which ABI they were built for? And if not: why don't they?

Comment: Because these scanners have different interfaces, different JNI

Comment: Then why not write a wrapper API on top of them as a native library that you build for all ABIs that you support?

Comment: Yes :) I think about this. After all need something to understand current ABI in running app, it's time for open source!